# Need help to check if a JSON object (tag) exists. Tried array_key_exists and not sure how to use isset()

Tags: php, json

I'm new to PHP and trying to understand an existing code and modify it for a new requirement. This PHP code is called from 3rd party RESTful service using JSON. Here is the part of the code.

```
$json = json_decode(utf8_encode(file_get_contents("php://input")),TRUE);

// I have to check if the following object exists

$json["ROOT"]["APPLICANT"]["APPLICANT_CUSTOM_QUESTIONS"]["EMPLOYEES_ALLOWANCE_MARITAL_STATUS_CODE"]
// and if it exists then assign the following

$l_fed_filing_status = $json["ROOT"]["APPLICANT"]["APPLICANT_CUSTOM_QUESTIONS"]["EMPLOYEES_ALLOWANCE_MARITAL_STATUS_CODE"];

$l_fed_allowances = $json["ROOT"]["APPLICANT"]["FORM_ANSWERS"]["W4_IL_EMPLOYEES_ALLOWANCE_TOTAL"];

$l_fed_exempt = $json["ROOT"]["APPLICANT"]["FORM_ANSWERS"]["W4_IL_EMPLOYEES_ALLOWANCE_EXEMPT"];

$l_fed_addtl_amt = $json["ROOT"]["APPLICANT"]["FORM_ANSWERS"]["W4_IL_EMPLOYEES_ALLOWANCE_ADDITIONAL_AMOUNT"];

$l_fed_addtl_amt = str_replace("$", "", $l_fed_addtl_amt);

$l_w2_consent = $json["ROOT"]["APPLICANT"]["FORM_ANSWERS"]["W4_IL_W2_CONSENT"];

// If that JSON object or tag doesn't exists then I have to assign the following. 

$l_fed_filing_status = $json["ROOT"]["APPLICANT"]["W4"]["EMPLOYEES_ALLOWANCE_MARITAL_STATUS"];

$l_fed_allowances = $json["ROOT"]["APPLICANT"]["W4"]["EMPLOYEES_ALLOWANCE_TOTAL"];

$l_fed_exempt = $json["ROOT"]["APPLICANT"]["W4"]["EMPLOYEES_ALLOWANCE_EXEMPT"];

$l_fed_addtl_amt = $json["ROOT"]["APPLICANT"]["W4"]["EMPLOYEES_ALLOWANCE_ADDITIONAL_AMOUNT"];

$l_fed_addtl_amt = str_replace("$", "", $l_fed_addtl_amt);

$l_w2_consent = '';
```

How do i do that? I read about isset and array_exists and not sure how to code it. I tried `if (array_key_exists("EMPLOYEES_ALLOWANCE_MARITAL_STATUS_CODE", $json))`, but the control still went into that part of the IF even though  `EMPLOYEES_ALLOWANCE_MARITAL_STATUS_CODE` was not part of the JSON data. It should have gone to the else part. It gave the following error:

```
nNotice: Undefined index: W4_IL_EMPLOYEES_ALLOWANCE_TOTAL in 
getStringC.php on line 134\n\nNotice: Undefined index: W4_IL_EMPLOYEES_ALLOWANCE_EXEMPT in getStringC.php on line 135\n\nNotice: Undefined index: W4_IL_EMPLOYEES_ALLOWANCE_ADDITIONAL_AMOUNT in getStringC.php on line 136\n\nNotice: Undefined index: W4_IL_W2_CONSENT in getStringC.php on line 138
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: `array_key_exists`, as far as I know, only checks the first layer of the array. So in your case it is going to check for items that are at the same depth of `ROOT` in `$json`.

Answer (score 1):

I would just singled out your general variables and then do your checking:

```
$applicant = $json["ROOT"]["APPLICANT"];
$questions = $applicant["APPLICANT_CUSTOM_QUESTIONS"];
$answers = $applicant["FORM_ANSWERS"];
$w4 = $applicant["W4"];
...
$l_fed_filing_status = isset($questions["EMPLOYEES_ALLOWANCE_MARITAL_STATUS_CODE"]) ? $questions["EMPLOYEES_ALLOWANCE_MARITAL_STATUS_CODE"] : null;
...
```

Comment: I will try yours and Serhii (below) and let you all know. Thank you all for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if(isset($json["ROOT"]["APPLICANT"]["APPLICANT_CUSTOM_QUESTIONS"]["EMPLOYEES_ALLOWANCE_MARITAL_STATUS_CODE"])) {
    $l_fed_filing_status = $json["ROOT"]["APPLICANT"]["APPLICANT_CUSTOM_QUESTIONS"]["EMPLOYEES_ALLOWANCE_MARITAL_STATUS_CODE"];
}

// ....
```

or better:

```
$l_fed_filing_status = isset($json["ROOT"]["APPLICANT"]["APPLICANT_CUSTOM_QUESTIONS"]["EMPLOYEES_ALLOWANCE_MARITAL_STATUS_CODE"]) ? $json["ROOT"]["APPLICANT"]["APPLICANT_CUSTOM_QUESTIONS"]["EMPLOYEES_ALLOWANCE_MARITAL_STATUS_CODE"] : '';
```

Some template:

```
$var = isset($json[key1][key2]) : $json[key1][key2] ? 'default value';
```

or if you're using PHP 7+

```
$var = $json[key1][key2] ?? 'default value';
```

and define some intermediate variables, as @i-- mentioned

Comment: Both yours and the one above worked. Thank you all for your help.